# PayPal Invoice Shipping_Cost in REST APA with PHP

Tags: php, invoice, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been trying for two days to include the shipping_cost object with a Create Invoice request.  If I leave shipping_cost out my code works fine.
Including shipping_cost requires the following syntax I think.

```
<code>
use PayPal\Api\ShippingCost;
<code>
$invoice
    ->setMerchantInfo(new MerchantInfo())
    ->setBillingInfo(array(new BillingInfo()))
    ->setNote($brwNote)
    ->setPaymentTerm(new PaymentTerm())
    ->setShippingInfo(new ShippingInfo())
    ->setShippingCost(new ShippingCost());
<code>
$invoice->getShippingCost()
     ->setAmount(6.80);
```

When I run my code I get the following response:
ERROR:Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices.

I have opened a ticket with PayPal just now because of the 500 error, but I have to believe this is a syntax problem.  Does anyone use the Invoice API and specify Shipping Cost?  What syntax are you specifying.

Thanks!